# Error connecting gitlab ci pipeline to redis service

Tags: python, django, docker, redis, gitlab

I have been having issues connecting my redis to my gitlab ci to run some tests

I keep getting this error

`Error -2 connecting to redis:6379. Name does not resolve`

This is my docker-compose.yml section for redis

```
redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

and this is my .gitlab.ci file

```
image: docker:19.03.5
services:
  - docker:19.03.5-dind
  - redis:latest

stages:
  - Build
  - Push

variables:
  APK_CACHE: "/etc/cache/apk"
  REDIS_PORT: 6379
  REDIS_HOST: redis
  REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379



before_script:
  - apk add python3
  - apk add --update docker-compose
  - docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py test --parallel"

Build:
  stage: Build
  before_script: []
  script:
    - mkdir data/
    - docker build --compress -t ecr_image .
    - docker save --output data/image.tar ecr_image
  artifacts:
    name: image
    paths:
      - data/
```